# Binding C++ and Fortran

Tags: c++, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I want to combine C++ and Fortran together. My Fortran code will use a C++ function and C++ function changes variables of Fortran and sends them back. The C++ function is built with other C++ codes, e.g. the C++ function will use some sub-function in other .cpp file. I make the Fortran code with `ifort` and I added that C++ function as one object file, test.o in my Fortran makefile. I also put every needed C++ .o file(support test.o) in makefile.  It shows the error

> #6633, "The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument".

Here is the code.

Fortran code

```
  use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING, only: C_INT, C_DOUBLE   
  implicit double precision(a-h,o-z),integer(i-n)
  Interface
   integer (C_INT) function SolveBIE_(x, y, aa, m) BIND(C, NAME='SolveBIE_')
   use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
   implicit none
   type (C_PTR), value :: x
   type (C_PTR), value :: y
   type (C_PTR), value :: aa
   integer (C_INT), value :: m
   end function SolveBIE_
  end Interface
  integer (C_INT) :: m
  real (C_DOUBLE), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:), target :: x
  real (C_DOUBLE), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:), target :: y
  real (C_DOUBLE), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:), target :: aa
  ALLOCATE(x(0:MAXLEN,MAXINTERFACES))
  ALLOCATE(y(0:MAXLEN,MAXINTERFACES))
  ALLOCATE(aa(0:MAXLEN,MAXINTERFACES))
```

My Fortran code run

```
  mm = SolveBIE_(x(1,1),y(1,1),aa(1,1),m)
```

Using the C++ code and where the error is from, on `x, y, aa` 
I use `x(1,1)` instead of `x`, because if using `x`, then there is another error

> #6634,"the shape matching rules of actual arguments and dummy arguments have been violated"`

I don't understand why it should be `x(1,1)`. Why is this working, not `x`?

My C++ code

```
  #ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
  #endif
  int solveBIE_(double *ini_bdry_x, double *ini_bdry_y, double *ini_bdry_um, int *fM)
{  
     double(*bdry_node)[2] = new double[M1][2];
     for (int k = 0; k < M; k++) {
        bdry_node[k+1][0] = ini_bdry_x[k+1];
        bdry_node[k+1][1] = ini_bdry_y[k+1];
        bdry_theta[k+1] = Atan(ini_bdry_x[k+1], ini_bdry_y[k+1]);}

    ... some functions in other .cpp file
```

Comment: Follow this [tutorial](http://docs.cray.com/books/S-2179-52/html-S-2179-52/ppgzmrwh.html) and ask for help when you get stuck

Comment: It would be helpful to break that first paragraph up a little.  And also give the full error message.  However, the error message, if it's referring to the arguments to `SolveBIE_` seems quite clear to me (`type(c_ptr)` and `real(c_double)` aren't the same).  What is it you don't understand about it?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying. Especially not the bit about `x` and `x(1,1)`. Please always show the complete code and the complete error message (or the whole output).

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez That tutorial is *very* obsolete. The OP is using techniques which are much more modern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your interface is written, you have to construct a `C_PTR` to array `x` and pass that as the first argument:

```
use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING, only: C_INT, C_DOUBLE, C_PTR, C_LOC
! ...
type(C_PTR) PTRx
! ...
PTRx = C_LOC(x(LBOUND(x,1),LBOUND(x,2)))
! ...
mm = solveBIE_(PTRx, PTRy, PTRaa, m)
```

As shown above, you would have to fix the next two arguments as well. But you need to rewrite the interface for argument `fM` because as matters stand, Fortran will pass an integer by value whereas C++ is expecting a pointer. Given that, I would rewrite the interface completely, using the names given for the arguments in the C++ function and passing everything by reference. Names for dummy arguments are potentially visible in Fortran, so it's useful for them to be meaningful. In the following I assume that `fM` points to a scalar in the callee:

```
  Interface
   function SolveBIE_(ini_bdry_x, ini_bdry_y, ini_bdry_um, fM) &
      BIND(C, NAME='SolveBIE_')
   import
   implicit none
   integer(C_INT) SolveBIE_
   real(C_DOUBLE) :: ini_bdry_x(*)
   real(C_DOUBLE) :: ini_bdry_y(*)
   real(C_DOUBLE) :: ini_bdry_um(*)
   integer (C_INT) :: fM
   end function SolveBIE_
  end Interface
```

Then later on you can invoke it more or less normally as

```
mm = SolveBIE_(x,y,aa,m)
```

Note that `x(1,1)` was wrong because `LBOUND(x,1) = 0`, not `1`!

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I have a question, should I use the same way to define the ini_bdry_x(*), e.g. real (C_DOUBLE), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:), target :: x ALLOCATE(x(0:MAXLEN,MAXINTERFACES)) Because I need to set value for them, then pass them to C++. So it is necessary to define them firstly.

Comment: Right, you have to do all that other stuff that you're already doing. My intent was not to rewrite your whole program for you, just to present the changes I would make.

Comment: Thank you. There is no error now. But I have a compile error. I posted as another question. Here is the link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48696645/compile-error-when-binding-c-and-fortran